# Debian console graphic error

Tags: terminal, putty, ncurses

when I try to install something over Putty, it looks like this:
[image: terminal window showing missing drawing characters]

so really buggy :).
Has anyone a suggestion for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably something to do with UTF-8 handling on different terminal types.

You could try this solution I found on `linux.debian.user`:

> What release of PuTTY are you using? I'm using PuTTY 0.63, which is
> the latest release. In this version, the default value for the terminal
> type string is xterm. At least it is for me. I have to explicitly change
> it to putty, even after setting the remote character set to UTF-8. Make
> sure the terminal type string is all lower case. Terminal type strings
> are case sensitive. They have to match the terminal type definition in
> ncurses. The putty terminal type definition in ncurses can be found in
> /usr/share/terminfo/p. You can also try a terminal type string of
> [xterm-utf8](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#toc-_X_T_E_R_M). This terminal type definition in ncurses is found in
> /usr/share/terminfo/x. The latest version of PuTTY can be downloaded
> here:
>
> [http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty)

in this discussion: [Debian and Unicode line drawing](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/linux.debian.user/Yy-kQu1RC44)

Answer (score 0):

It's *indirectly* related to UTF-8: the PuTTY developers chose to ignore VT100 line-drawing control sequences when UTF-8 encoding is used.  Doing that requires any application that uses line-drawing to do some workaround.

You can work around this by one of these methods:

- setting the [`NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-NCURSES_NO_UTF8_ACS) environment variable, as noted in the manual page, or
- using a correct terminal description such as [**`putty`**](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-putty), which happens to have a special capability **`U8`** defined, telling ncurses the same thing as the environment variable.